# Workbook reference via VBA doesn't accept variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up references to other workbooks, whereby the location is static: `G:\XY\XY\[Workbook2019.xlsx]2019-04'!C1`

Since these references change depending on what month it is, I want, for ease of use, set up an input-box where one can type in a number like 01 or 04 and it would exchange the month part in the reference.

My code looks like this so far:

```
Sub MonthRef()
    Dim strMonth As String

    strMonth = InputBox("Enter month as interger (e.g. 01 for Jan; 02 for Feb.)", "Month")
    Range("B4").Formula = "='G:\XY\[XY.xlsx]2019-" & strMonth & " '!C1"
End Sub
```

weirdly enough, I seem to get the correct reference, but the cell wont accept the number for some reason and prompts me to select one of the sheets from a workbook.

I cannot seem to find the problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Tom can you highlight where your code is different to mine? I cannot seem to find the distinction..

Comment: @SJR sorry. I have edited the reference. i seem to have forgotten the bracket in my question. The code itself is correct.

Comment: Do you have a space after the month number? Best to assign the whole string to a variable and then you can check its precise value.

Comment: @SJR there actually is a space after the month number! WTH!? How am i to avoid that? EDIT: silly me - as you correctly indicated, i left a space following the variable string. Thanx!

Comment: You should probably handle your user input as well to ensure the user doesn't lead a trailing space. Simply `Trim`ing the value should take care of it

Comment: @Tom thanks for the tip with thre Trim function! I wouldn't have thought of that!

Comment: @AndyJames I had a few more suggestions that are longer then a comment to try and safeguard the input as well so have posted as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd flesh this out a little further to avoid other mistakes from user input as well. This can be done by using a function to test the user input is the correct criteria and looping until either it is, or the user cancels

```
Private Function TestUserInput(v As String) As Boolean
    TestUserInput = False

    If IsNumeric(v) And Len(v) <= 2 Then
        If CLng(v) > 0 And CLng(v) <= 12 Then
            TestUserInput = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub MonthRef()
    Dim strMonth As String
    Dim IsUserInputValid As Boolean
    Dim InputBoxPrompt As String

    InputBoxPrompt = "Enter month as integer (e.g. 01 for Jan; 02 for Feb.)"

    Do
        strMonth = Trim(InputBox(InputBoxPrompt, "Month"))

        ' Test if strMonth is valid
        IsUserInputValid = TestUserInput(strMonth)

        ' Handle User cancelled
        If strMonth = vbNullString Then
            Exit Sub
        ' If input is not valid then prompt user
        ElseIf IsUserInputValid = False Then
            MsgBox prompt:="Input not valid. " & InputBoxPrompt, Title:="Error"
        End If
        ' Loop until input is valid or User cancels
    Loop Until IsUserInputValid

    Range("B4").Formula= "='G:\XY\[XY.xlsx]2019-" & Format(strMonth, "00") & "'!C1"
End Sub
```